# How to rearrange formula - Error correction models

Tags: self-study, ecm

I am studying a time series subject but I am really struggling with the maths. Could someone please help me get from the first equation to the second equation? Apparently it has been reparameterised but I dont know where to start.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's easier to go from the bottom one to the top one

Comment: What do you think about my answer? Do you need any further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

These equations are the same except for $(b_1+b_2)x_{t-1}$ vs. $-\lambda\beta_1 x_{t-1}$.
Since both equations have the same $\Delta y_t$ on the left hand side, $(b_1+b_2)x_{t-1}=-\lambda\beta_1 x_{t-1}$.
$x_{t-1}$ is a common multiplier, so you can divide both sides by it.
Then you get $(b_1+b_2)=-\lambda\beta_1$, which then immediately yields what you need.